# retain and keep old values of textboxfor after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i get query string like this :

`http://localhost:52518/?Culture=en&hid=10000&Arrival=21-05-2017&Departure=22-05-2017&Adults=1&Children=0&Rooms=1`

after i click the submit button i get it like this :

`http://localhost:51518/?Parameters.Checkin=21-05-2017&Parameters.Checkout=22-05-2017&Rooms=1&Adults=1&Children=0`

the problem is `Parameters.Checkout` i don't want to be like this i want to be `Arrival` like first link i mentioned it above .

this is the `.cshtml` :

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
                {
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <p class="font">@Resource.criteria_Arrival</p>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Parameters.Checkin, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "calendarr font", @id = "Arrival",  @name = "Arrival",  @readonly = "readonly", @onchange = "changedDate();" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-2">
                            <p class="font">@Resource.criteria_Departure</p>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Parameters.Checkout, "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", new { @class = "calendarr font", @id = "Departure",  @name = "Departure",  @readonly = "readonly" })
                        </div>
 }
```

i don't know where the problem because at first load the query loaded successfully but the second load change the arrival to checkin

Comment: Read the comments before you delete previous question `@name = ".."` does nothing fortunately (otherwise model binding would never work correctly). Use a view model with properties `Arrival` and `Departure` if that is what you want your names to be.

Comment: you mean use like this  `Model => Model.Arrival ` and remove @name = ".." attribute  ??

Comment: Yes (except don't use capital M `Model`) and you can remove the `id = "..."` as well

Comment: @StephenMuecke  i did it with `@Name="Arrival" ` capital not small `@name=".."`

Comment: DO NOT do that! Bind to a model. you may as well not even be using razor if your going to do dreadful hack like that! NEVER EVER EVER change the `value` or `name` attributes when using the `HtmlHelper` methods.

Comment: @StephenMuecke can you explain the problem more to got your point i am not understand you clear